# dense rank in sql

Tags: sql, window-functions

I want to get a dense rank as shown below.

```
select dense_rank() over(order by seller_state),* from (
select seller_state,(row_number() over(PARTITION BY seller_state order by seller_state)-1)% 5+1 as rn
FROM table
WHERE seller_state in ('Maharashtra','Haryana'));
```

[image]

Comment: Add script for create table, sample data and expected result. Don't add images to send informations.

Comment: 'I want to get a dense rank as shown below.' - please state your issue.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need in this:

```sql
SELECT *,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY seller_state) - 1) DIV 5 + 1 group_no,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY seller_state) - 1) MOD 5 + 1 no_in_group
FROM table
WHERE seller_state in ('Maharashtra','Haryana'));
```

?